# Why my uploaded image didn't show on my php page?

Tags: php, html

Below is a main page for uploaded page:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="display.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pro_image">
    <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="image" id="image"/>
    <br><img id="blah" src="profile pic.jpg" alt="your image" width="160px" height="120px"/><br/>
</form>
```

Incorporated with the image display page(display.php) script:

```
<?php
 $dir="upload/";
 $name=$_FILES['image']['name']; 
 $tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 move_uploaded_file($tmp,$dir.$name);

 ?>

 <br /><img src="".$dir.$name."" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Anyone can help me to point out what the actual problem on `display.php` and correct my script?The image didn't show as desired on the page.

the output of display.php as show above:
[image]

Comment: uhh, have you tried encasing your image in PHP tags? <img src="<?php echo $dir.$name;?>" width="100" height="100"/>

Comment: @Ninsuo ,I had try,but not work,the page show me the box and inside the box got small default image as what we alway see the actual image didn't show off in certain forum or profile-pic

Answer (score 4):

you forgot `<?php   ?>` here

```
<img src="<?php echo $dir.$name; ?>" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Comment: I had try your suggestion,but fail

Comment: use inspect element in firefox and see what path this image tag is having.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar I had check the directory where i move the image file to it and found that the image file is not inside the directory.Is it mean that the php script to move the file to `upload` directory is fail?

Comment: @JCChan See the folder permission of `upload` folder. make it writable.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar How to make it?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I had visit your giving website,there are too many solution,Which one is the best one for it?Because this is 1st time I meet it and don't understand about it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29349/discussion-between-jcchan-and-yogesh-suthar)

Answer (score 1):

Your `display.php` file is a php file and you are try to show the variable data without echoing it in this file use it.

```
<img src="<?php echo $dir.$name; ?>" width="100" height="100"/>
```

**EDITED:**

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp,$dir.$name) or die("There is error in uploading");
```

Comment: @JCChan perhaps src is not getting the proper path. check your upload folder is near to your display.php file.

Comment: which platform you using means windows or linux?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29357/discussion-between-jcchan-and-miss-poo)

Comment: The output show the `There is error in uploading`...What does it mean?

Comment: Yes, Now you have got your problem. your problem is in uploading not in html code.

Comment: what did you mean in html code?Yup,I trying this on my computer.

Comment: Should I have to change display.php extension to html?Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JCChan no need of changing the extension. I just ask to know where can we the problem.

Comment: @JCChan well try with the path `$dir="C://xamp/htdocs/project_name/path_to_folder/upload/";` and this will work.

Comment: I actually use the `Uniform server` for my project and store `upload` inside it.So,all my project files is store on it within the `www`.Is it have to change my project's folder shift to `Xampp`?

Comment: No need to change the server, you should provide the full path of upload folder to `$dir` variable. I gave only example to you.

Comment: I'm change the path location already,but still show the `There is error in uploading`...

Comment: I use this path: `$dir="C:/UniServer/www/form/upload/";`

Answer (score 0):

1. As first thing check that ur images uploaded properly on uploads/ folder. there is changes of permission issue to upload the images.
2. then check manually accessing images by giving URL
   http://test.com/uploads/image1.jpg
3. if all this debug with firebug what path is getting shown in
4. if this path is wrong try to use absolute path rather than relative.

Comment: how to use the absolute path?

Comment: why i directed into homepage of the link?is not the  http://test.com/uploads/image1.jpg